# Suggest a good PHP wiki engine

Tags: php, wiki, wiki-engine

I am looking for a small wiki engine that is easy to embed into an existing PHP application.  Or perhaps a set of libraries to handle all the typical wiki functions.

Currently I am using [ErfurtWiki](http://erfurtwiki.sourceforge.net/), but it is starting to show its age.  It hasn't been updated since 2005, and several of the pages on sourceforge appear to have been [hacked](http://erfurtwiki.sourceforge.net/MailingList).

I will be including it with a GPLv2 application so a GPL compatible license is important.

Edit:

To update, mostly I am just looking for text formatting/parser functionality.  I want to deal with the storage, security, rev history, etc on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pear::Text_Wiki](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki) is another option, albeit it only handles the case of text formatting. It has not been updated since June of 2007, but includes several Wiki formats (all of which have other latest release dates).

The formats that Text_Wiki supports are:

- BBCode: latest release: 2006-12-23
- CoWiki: latest release: 2007-01-02
- Creole: latest release: 2007-08-01
- Doku: latest release: 2005-10-14
- MediaWiki: latest release: 2006-04-10
- Tiki: latest release: 2005-10-14

It has an LGPL license, so there should be no licensing problems with including in a GPL project.

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), the wiki engine that runs wikipedia.

EDIT: As per your comment, MediaWiki is highly embeddable. I've integrated it in numerous projects over the years.

Comment: If you are looking for integration points it may help to take a look at the integration with phpBB: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PHPBB/Users_Integration

Comment: MediaWiki doesn't work to me.  It is far, far more then what I need.  I need something that I can small that I can embed in an existing system.

Comment: You should indicate that in your question though, as it is not clear. Also, please explain why is it too much - how will it hurt you to use it in your application?

Answer (score 4):

I've used [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) in the past and have been fairly happy with it. It's pretty small, the code isn't the cleanest, but it's not too tough to drop in your own authentication scheme (for example) to integrate with an existing user system.

It is GPL2, which fits your requirement. It uses the file system as storage, so may not scale that well, but for basic wiki stuff with a decent feature set it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I love DokuWiki - it may be file-based but it's an excellent piece of software. We use it at http://wiki.php.net/

Answer (score 0):

I like DokuWiki, but pmWiki might be better for you. Here's a list of all the PHP wikis: http://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php?sid=183